# creating user login hook for custom module

Tags: javascript, drupal-7, drupal-modules

I have created a custom module in drupal 7.I want to add user login hook in my custom module 'one_time_popup' is my module name and enable it.I want to create a hook for user_login ie)when login was successful need to do the event given inside the hook.the below function doesn't include js file

```
function one_time_popup_user_login($edit, $user){
if(user_is_logged_in){
drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('module', 'one_time_popup') . '/service.js');
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the below code

```
function one_time_popup_user_login(&$edit, $account) {
  if (user_is_logged_in()) {
    drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('module', 'one_time_popup') . '/service.js');
  }
}
```

Otherwise use this

```
 function one_time_popup_init() {
      if (user_is_logged_in()) {
        drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('module', 'one_time_popup') . '/service.js');
      }
    }
```

include js in your one_time_popup module

Comment: Refer this https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21user%21user.api.php/function/hook_user_login/7.x